# How can I use a tif and a SID to make a basemap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to add a basemap in QGIS, projected correctly for PA.  I have been directed to [PASDA](http://www.pasda.psu.edu/uci/MetadataDisplay.aspx?entry=PASDA&file=PAMAP_iCubed_2010.xml&dataset=76).  When I click on the FTP download link, it gives me the option to download TIF data or SID data.  What do I want, and how will I add it to QGIS as a basemap?

Comment: Specifically, the link above is for PA's orthoimagery.

Answer (score 1):

SID requires a special driver, which does not have an open source compatible license.

So I would prefer the TIF data, which is fully supported by QGIS. After unzipping, you can add the data as Raster file to QGIS.

But using the WMS service they offer might be much easier.